# Can't prepare PRAGMA queries on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Having this line

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(?)", new String[] {tableName});
```

and getting this:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error: , while compiling: PRAGMA table_info(?)`

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try temporarily hard-wiring in a table name. If that works, then you cannot use positional parameters for pragma parameters -- you'd just need to do some string concatenation yourself.

Comment: That was it. If I use string.format works great. A bug to submit.

Comment: Not sure whether that's an Android limitation or a SQLite limitation.

Comment: I've had chronic problems with the rawQuery using bindargs. It appears to be broken until at least O.S 2.1. I've always had to resort to dirty string concatenation or String.replace